# Función para contar la frecuencia de un valor con respecto a días, semana y meses

Tags: javascript, function

espero que estén muy bien. Aclaro el caso de uso. Un usuario se comunica y entra al sistema, capturo su número de línea por ejemplo 54321, y lo almaceno en una BD. Entonces, luego de eso, agrego una variable `contador` que, si el número lo encuentra en la BD le suma +1, entonces si el número se comunica 4 veces pues la variable `contador` será 4 y así sucesivamente.

Pero entonces necesito enviar en una `variable` el número de línea más la variable `contador` en 3 diferentes campos

```
Primer campo = número de veces que ingresa esa línea en un día
Segundo campo = número de veces que ingresa esa línea en una semana
Tercer campo = número de veces que ingresa esa línea en un mes
```

Y que cuando se cumpla el primer campo reinicie el contador y quede en 1 para el siguiente día, y así con el campo de la semana y el mes. Solo puedo utilizar una función en Js, para realizar este problema. Les agradecería su ayuda.

Yo estaba pensando en lo siguiente

```
var fecha = '2022-11-03T21:21:16.175Z';

function dia (fecha){
  
new Date();
var hoy = new Date();
let diaMilisegundos = 86400000;
let suma = hoy.getTime() - diaMilisegundos;
var contadorDia;

if(hoy == fecha){
for (contadorDia = 1; contadorDia <= 1000; contadorDia++)
    {
       return  contadorDia;
    }
}
  return contadorDia = 1
}

dia (fecha);
```

Pero para el `primer campo`, luego se me empieza a descontrolar todo jaja agradecería su ayuda

Comment: *en un intervalo de tiempo* -> me hace entender que quieres ejecutar una función cada cierto tiempo para recibir resultados (o valores como dices). Podrías usar [setTimeout](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/eventos-de-tiempo-en-javascript-settimeout-y-setinterval/)

Comment: Si, la función se ejecutaría, apenas reciba el valor, y que realice un conteo y me diga cuantas veces por ejemplo ah ingresado ese valor, durante el día. Y lo mismo pero que haga como un reporte, y realice el conteo de cuantas veces ah ingresado a la semana y luego en el mes

Comment: ¿Usas bases de datos?, tal como lo planteas no conozco una función que haga lo que  necesitas, tendrías que hacerla, toda la información de un mes, ¿Dónde la vas a almacenar para después tratarla?, puedes dar más contexto

Comment: Haz intentado algo? tienes un código de referencia? Edita tu pregunta y danos más detalles.

Comment: Si claro, el valor de entrada lo voy almacenando en una BD

Comment: no se entiende muy bien, tienes un codigo para ayudarnos a aclarar la situacion? igualmente creo que lo mejor seria ingresar la fecha en la bd en la cual fue echo el ingreso y asi consultas dependiendo del dia, mes, año o la hora, pero nose si ese es tu objetivo

Comment: Si, la pregunta es confusa... hablas de que quieres un funcion en javascript para contar frecuencias... y luego dices que vas a almacenar los datos un una BD... especifica mejor tu problema, cuéntanos que datos vas a almacenar, como, donde, cuando y que estructura de datos vas a manejar, en que BD la vas a almacenar y danos la mayor cantidad de información posible para dar una respuesta. Probablemente lo que quieres contar son eventos, entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es registrar el evento con una fecha, guardarlo en BD y luego con consultas a la BD consultarias agrupandola por mes o dia

Comment: ya la corrijo, discúlpenme porfa